# How to load multiple fixtures related one to each other properly?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures

This is my first attempt of loading multiple fixtures, most of each are related to each other.

I need to enter the fixtures as without them I am not able to test if crud fields are working as expected.

When I do so, I am facing Circular Reference error. I tried to apply some of the solutions none of which led me to solve the problem.

I have tried:
-DependentFixtureInterface (lead to Circular Reference)
-using groups (I tried to load the fixtures separately excluding properties that are fields related to other entites)

```
class {

protected $faker;
private $referencesIndex = [];

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->faker = Factory::create();
    $this->faker->addProvider(new FakerCompany());
    $this->faker->addProvider(new FakerPerson());


    $minTimeStamp = strtotime("2017-01-01");


    for ($i = 0; $i < 600; $i++) {
        $workOrder = new WorkOrder;
        //(1)handling start dates and end dates
        $randomStartDate = mt_rand($minTimeStamp, time());
        $dateTimeStartDate = new \DateTime($randomStartDate);
        $days = rand(30, 360);
        $endDate = $randomStartDate + $days * 86400;
        $dateTimeEndDate = new \DateTime($endDate);
        $workOrder->setStartDate($dateTimeStartDate);
        $workOrder->setEndDate($dateTimeEndDate);
        //(2)handling pay rate and bill rate
        $payRate = rand(30, 200);
        $billRate = $payRate / (1 - (1 / (rand(2, 10))));
        $workOrder->setPayRate = $payRate;
        $workOrder->setBillrate = $billRate;

        //(3)handling isRemote
        $workOrder->setIsRemote($this->faker->boolean(10));
        //(4)handling User
        foreach ($this->referenceRepository->getReference('user') as 
          $key => $val) {
            $workOrder->setUser($val);
        }



        foreach ($this->referenceRepository
        ->getReference('contractor') as $key => $val) {
            $workOrder->setContractor($val);
        }



        foreach ($this->referenceRepository->getReference('client') 
              as $key => $val) {
            $workOrder->setClient($val);
        }


        $manager->persist($workOrder);
    }
    $manager->flush();

    $this->addReference('workOrder', $workOrder);
}

public function getDependencies()
{
    return array(
        ClientFixtures::class,
        ContractorFixtures::class,
        UserFixtures::class
    );
}

 public static function getGroups(): array
 {
     return ['group1'];
 }
```

}

When I use command

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --group=group1
```

it leads me to another error saying: 'The "AppBundle\Entity\WorkOrder" fixture class is trying to be loaded, but is not available. Make sure this class is defined as a service and tagged with "doctrine.fixture.orm"

I expected any of the above approach to be correct, but apparently I am missing something important.

Comment: the DependentFixtureInterface and reference set and get should be the way to achieve this The circular reference error sounds like you might have errors in you fixture files getDependencies definitions (i.e. having circular dependencies between your fixtures).

Comment: Thank you for comment. How to define dependencies in getDependencies, when, in fact, fixtures refer to each other? It results from OneToMany relations between my entities.

Comment: The dependency relation between fixtures should be just one way - and the way shouldn't matter unless you have defined some side of the relationship to be mandatory. I.e. you can leave fixture a. without dependency that just creates one type of entity instances first (with setting the entity references) - and another fixture b that has dependency to fixtures a that creates the other entities and here the fixture would also set the reference between the entities (created in fixtures a and b).

Comment: hmpf, "(with setting the entity references)" = "(without setting the entity references)"

Comment: @Ejuhjav that totally makes sense to me.  I'll give it a try and hope to finalky overcome that impasse:-) thank you for your support